# customer is logged in from external file but on magento appear logged off

Tags: magento-1.8

Hi i am trying to login customer from external site which is on the same domain...just integrating the main site with magento....so both the main site and magento have common accounts

here is the code i am running...this does get a new customer created and if already exist logged in but when i go to Magento home page I still get the login and signup buttons....the user does not shows up to be logged in

Please let me know what i am doing wrong or what modification i have to do with magento

---

```
require_once ("magento/app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
$customer->loadByEmail($db2->f('mem_email'));
$customer->setStore($store);

$mageRunCode = isset ( $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] ) ? $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
$mageRunType = isset ( $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] ) ? $_SERVER ['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';

$app = Mage::app ( $mageRunCode, $mageRunType );

try {

    $customer->email = $db2->f('mem_email');
    $customer->password_hash = md5($password);
    if($customer->save()){
        //echo $customer->firstname." ".$customer->lastname." information is saved!";
    }else{
        echo "An error occured while saving customer";
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    // If customer already exists, initiate login

    if(preg_match('/This customer email already exists/', $e)){
        $customer->loadByEmail($db2->f('mem_email'));
        $session =Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $session->start();
        $session->login($db2->f('mem_email'), $password);
        $session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);
        $session->isLoggedIn() ? $session->getCustomer()->getName().' is online!' : 'not logged in';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `$session->login()` was successful, it renews the session id. This means, if the script is not able to send the new cookie or sends it with the wrong path, the session is lost to Magento.

#### What could have gone wrong?

1. "Headers already sent" error - something in your custom script omits output, so the HTTP header with the cookie information cannot be sent anymore. Make sure there is no output before you login the customer.
2. Cookie gets set for the right domain but for the wrong path. If your custom script runs is in a different subdirectory than Magento, make sure to configure the cookie path explicitly in Magento (System > Configuration > Web), use "/" if unsure.

#### How to debug

- Activate error logging in PHP and logging in Magento, look into the PHP error logs (often found in `/var/log/apache2/`, `/var/log/www` or `/var/log/php` - this is relative to root, not to the Magento installation directory) *and* the Magento log files in `var/log`
- Inspect the "frontend" cookie in your browser console (opens with `F12` in most browsers), check if it changes its value (the session id) after login and see what the domain and path are.